# How to properly use SVG icons in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have plenty of `.svg` icons and I would like to somehow incorporate them into my website. Each of these icons has different default `width` and `height` attributes. I would like to possibly easily use them when needed and I'm wondering  how to do it. My idea was to create a directory with the icons (each in a separate file) but I don't know whether I should use `i` tag, `span` tag or maybe `img` tag. I would like to have a high flexibility in terms of customizing them (width, ehight, fill etc) - which approach do you recommend?

Comment: So you have a directory full of various SVGs with differing aspect ratios, and you want to render them all at the same aspect ratio within your website? Do you have a few SVG examples, or how you want to include them on your page? You want to use the `<img>` tag. Alternatively, you can build a font from the SVG icons using a tool like [Glyphter](https://glyphter.com/). Then you can use an `<i>` tag like FontAwesome to render font glyphs instead of individual SVGs. You could also add all the SVGs to one giant SVG and load it once. Then use the `<use>` element to access individual "sprites".

Comment: Take inspiration from existing icon libraries like fontAwesome Material icons etc. and adopt concepts that fit your needs.

Comment: is it a good idea to use `i` tag and `:before` pseudo class with `background-image: url(data:image...)`? I think this is the approach that StackOverflow uses